# Typescript. Добавить в папку ./build файлы *.pug

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, pug

Имеется подобная структура проекта:

```
-build
-src
    - router
       - index.ts
    - views
      - index.pug
    - app.ts
```

С помощью tsc собираю js в папку ./build.

И в эту папку попадают только js файлы.

А файлы отличные от *.js не попадают, к примеру *.pug файлы.

Как забилдить файлы *.pug в папку ./build? И возможно ли это вообще?

Вот tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "pretty": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./build",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "strict": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: .gitignore выхлопу js и хранить их в самой папке

Comment: изиняюсь, но я не понял)

Comment: в package.json добавил такую команду: "build": "tsc && cp -R src/views build/views && cp -R src/public build/public". Не знаю, насколько это правильное решение. Может есть более изящный подход?